# How to make a select on React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

With React Native, I want to make a select.

Right now, with PickerIOS, I have something that looks like this:

[image: Picker1]

As you can see, the picker shows a bunch of possible values even though I just want one to show up.

I'm trying to make it look more like this, so it only shows the value you have selected (unless you touch it, in which case a picker comes up from the bottom):

[image: Picker2]

What can I do?

Comment: The way this is done in native apps written in Swift or Objective-C is to create a `UITextField` and set its `inputView` to a `UIPickerView`. I have no idea whether the same is possible with React Native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React Native List Popover](https://github.com/bulenttastan/react-native-list-popover) might work for you.

[image]

Comment: But i have a issue in X code :No script URL provided. Make sure the packager is running or you have embedded a JS bundle in your application bundle.unsanitizedScriptURLString:((null))

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try [React Native FMPicker](https://github.com/peter4k/React-Native-FMPicker), which simulate the picker in your second screen shot